# Backend multiples apache 2.4 how to sync settings virtualhosts

Tags: linux, apache, backend, high-availability, apache2.4

I have a set of apache 2.4 backend (Ubuntu server) with the same virtualhost and same configurations (the content is accessible through an HTTPS balancer). How could I easily replicate this configuration between all apaches (Ubuntu Server)?

FrontEnd LB (HTTPS) -> backend (HTTP) multiple ubuntu servers LTS apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_proxy_balancer of apache 2.4: [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html).

You can look at HaProxy, if you want :

- [blog article on medium.com](https://medium.com/@alexmoran_19787/load-balance-multiple-frontends-and-backends-with-haproxy-651fee5606b3)
- [official website of HaProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/)

You can use many others like : Nginx, [Traefik](https://traefik.io/), [Neutrino](https://neutrinoslb.github.io/) and [gobetween](http://gobetween.io/).